# How to do anti-aliasing in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: antialiasing, opengl-es-3.0

I'd like to implement anti-aliasing in my android OpenGL ES app, but all the examples I found were super old and not helping at all or were using OpenGL on PCs. Could someone give a code example to implement more modern techniques of AA?

Comment: [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling), [LearnOpenGL - Anti Aliasing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Anti-Aliasing)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working with OpenGL ES on android, here and there's no window creation step where I can set it to multisample

Comment: The OpenGL context needs to be created somewhere. Alternatively you can render to a [Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object).

Comment: I guess. It would be a shame not to be able to enable MSAA, I wanted to test the performance.

Comment: @Gyoo You can enable it from developer options for testing: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options